# "File not found" when change root in config nginx

Tags: php, nginx, subdomain

I want to config auto create subdomain for my domain:

```
example.com -> source in /www/source/
abcd.example.com -> source in /www/source/abcd/
```

I was using this configuration:

```
server {
        listen 80; 
            server_name   ~^(.*)\.example\.com$; 
            # If a directory doesn't exist...
            if (!-d /www/source/$1) {
                rewrite . example.com redirect;
            }    
            # Sets the correct root
            root /www/source/$1;
            location ~* \.php$ {
                fastcgi_index   index.php;
                fastcgi_pass    127.0.0.1:9000;
                include         fastcgi_params;
                fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME    $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_NAME        $fastcgi_script_name;
            }
        }
```

In `/www/source/abcd/`, I have `index.php`. But it is not run. When I go to `abcd.example.com` I get "File not found."
I replaced `index.php` to `index.html`, and then it runs correctly.

How can fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a named capture as numeric captures can go out of scope.

For example:

```
server_name  ~^(?<subdomain>.*)\.example\.com$; 
root /www/source/$subdomain;
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html#regex_names) for more.